# Limit number of webservice call in Swift

Tags: ios, grand-central-dispatch

I need to do a lot of web service call - downloading images -, but want to limit it to 5 establish connection at the same time.  Do I need a `concurrent queue` or should I use `dispatch group`?

I think I need a queue, but an item **from queue should remove only when web service response returned**.

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on what you want achieve next.

If you want to wait all answer before going further, you should use `dispatch_group`, but if you want perform action ( like updating UI ) after each WS response, you need `concurrent queue`